# R Shiny - Update counter every x seconds based on a variable

Tags: r, shiny

I am messing around with this shiny app to try and make a clicker game, like cookie clicker for example. I have the initial clicker working correctly, but the growth over time is giving me trouble. What I attempted is below.

My issue starts below # * * * 2.1.6 Passive1 gain ----, the rest of the app works as intended.

How can I correctly make the counter increase over time based on the amount of passive1 owned? Maybe a tick every x seconds.

```
library(shiny)

# * 1.0 UI Setup ----

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Clicker",
             
             tabPanel("Game",
                      titlePanel("Points"),
                      
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          textOutput("Points")
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          h5("Click"),
                          h5("1 point per click"),
                          actionButton("click","Click"),
                          p(),
                          actionButton("passive1","Passive 1"),
                          textOutput("Passive1Cost"),
                          textOutput("Passive1Level"),
                          textOutput("Passive1Gain")
                        )))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  counter <- reactiveValues(countervalue = 0)
  
  # * 2.0 Main button ----
  observeEvent(input$click, {
    counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue + 1     
  })
  
  # * * 2.1 Passive1 Stats ----
  
  Passive1Level <- reactiveValues(countervalue = 0)
  Passive1Gain <- reactiveValues(countervalue = 0)
  Passive1Cost <- reactiveValues(countervalue = 10)

# * * * 2.1.1 Level up passive1 ----
observeEvent(input$passive1, {
  if(Passive1Cost$countervalue <= counter$countervalue)
  {Passive1Level$countervalue <- Passive1Level$countervalue + 1}
})

# * * * 2.1.2 Spent points for Passive1 -----
observeEvent(input$passive1, {
  if(Passive1Cost$countervalue <= counter$countervalue)
  {counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue - Passive1Cost$countervalue}
})  

# * * * 2.1.3 Increase cost of Passive1 ----
observeEvent(input$passive1, {
  {Passive1Cost$countervalue <- 10 * Passive1Level$countervalue + 10}
})

# * * * 2.1.4 Increasing Passive1 gain ----
observeEvent(input$passive1, {
  Passive1Gain$countervalue <- 5 * Passive1Level$countervalue
})  

# * * * 2.1.5 Output Passive1 stats ----

output$Passive1Cost <- renderText({
  paste("Cost:",Passive1Cost$countervalue)
})

output$Passive1Level <- renderText({
  paste("Quantity:",Passive1Level$countervalue)
})

output$Passive1Gain <- renderText({
  paste("Points per sec:", Passive1Gain$countervalue)
})

# * * * 2.1.6 Passive1 gain ----

#fails and crashes everything

# CurrentTime <- Sys.time()
# observe({
# if(CurrentTime + 1 > Sys.time()){counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue + Passive1Gain$countervalue}
# })

# does not even run  

# CurrentTime <- reactiveValues(Sys.time())
# observe({
# if(CurrentTime + 1){counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue + Passive1Gain$countervalue}
# })

#Also fails everytime

# vals <- reactiveValues(countervalue = 0)
# 
# observe({
#   invalidateLater(1000 / (counter$countervalue + Passive1Gain$countervalue), session)
#   # vals$countervalue <- isolate(vals$countervalue) + Passive1Gain$countervalue
#   # counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue + vals$countervalue
# })

#Also crashes

# observe({
# invalidateLater(1000, session)
#   counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue + Passive1Gain$countervalue
# })

# * 2.2 Point display ----

output$Points <- renderText({
  paste("Points:",counter$countervalue)
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```